# Clear badge icon using Parse

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, swift2, xcode7

I am using Parse for push notifications.
When sending a push adding a badge icon is simply done by checking a check box on parse, no code implementation required.

Problem is I can't seem to find a solution in the  [documentation](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications) for clear the badges on once the app is launched .

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your appdelegate.m:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    if (currentInstallation.badge != 0) {
        currentInstallation.badge = 0;
        [currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                // Handle error here with an alert…
            }
            else {
                // only update locally if the remote update succeeded so they always match
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

this should reset badge every time.